# Should the pointer be set to null after calling COM Release() function?

Tags: c++, com, interface

Assume we have a pointer to a com interface so my question is do we need to set the pointer to null after Release() call. Or else how COM handles it?

```
Func1()
{
.....
.....
pComInterface->Release();
pComInterface = NULL;  //---> Does this required? If used, then what is the impact?
}
```

Comment: If you intend on using `pComInterface` after the call to `Release()` then IMHO you should set it to null. Otherwise just leave it be.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: If during a code maintenance cycle some code is added after the `Release()` call, then if the pointer is not set to `NULL`/`nullptr`, there could be dangling references and hard to spot bugs (referencing an object _after_ `Release()` call). In general, I think the best thing to do is to use smart pointer classes like `ATL::CComPtr<>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `pComInterface` is a *raw* pointer to some COM interface, then from COM's point of view the important thing is to call `Release()` to properly manage the object lifetime. (COM has no idea if you set the raw pointer to `NULL` or not after a call to `Release()`.)

However, from the point of view of *good code quality*, you should set the pointer to `NULL` (or, better `nullptr` in C++11) after calling `Release()`, to be sure that you don't have a dangling reference to a previously released COM object, if you have some code following `Release()`.

(It's a similar case to `new` and `delete`: you must call `delete` after `new` to properly release  object's resources; you don't "need" to set the pointer to `nullptr` after `delete`, but it's a good coding practice to avoid dangling references to a deleted object.)

Moreover, even better is to use a **smart pointer** to manage the lifetime of COM object interfaces, like **`ATL::CComPtr`**. In this way, proper calls to `Release()` (and `AddRef()`) are made *automatically* for you.
(Continuing the comparison with `new` and `delete`, it's the same suggestion as preferring *smart pointers* like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` instead of raw owning pointers.)

Answer (score 7):

I assume `pComInterface` is a raw pointer, declared as e.g.:

`IFoo* pComInterface`

No, you don't need to NULL it - it's just your local variable. A call of `IUnknown::Release` is however mandatory since you notify the object that you release the pointer and the object can safely decrement its internal reference counter, if it has any.

Comment: If it is not a local variable of this function, then is it required? Also Release() doesn't set it to null, isn't it?

Comment: @RahulSundar `Release()` has no access to the storage you use for the interface pointer to begin with. It is *yours*. And I would prefer it a non-issue anyway by *proper* use of a COM interface smart pointer (of which there are several, two notable from Microsoft directly in the comutil library and ATL). (and +1 on the answer).

Comment: By "local" I mean more general "related to your code only". No, Release does not set it it `NULL` automatically.

Comment: I was wondering, COM requires `void**` parameter. Does this mean the other thread gets the pointer, as well as a reference to our local variable? For example can the external thread set `*ptr = NULL;` such that our `pComInterface` becomes `NULL`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I don't think this has the meaning you supposed above, the question here is not related to threading at all, in fact. I suggest that you post your concern as a separate question.